# Неодназначность перегрузки функции разными целыми типами

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++14

```
void f(long long v) { cout << 1; }
void f(int v) { cout << 2; }
int main() {
    long l = 2L;
    f(l);
    return 0;
}
```

Есть такой код, при этом ошибка компиляции - неоднозначность, а почему?!

Cтандарт C++ гарантирует, что

```
sizeof(int) <= sizeof(long) <= sizeof(long long)
```

И по правилам, расширение имеет больше приоритет чем стандартное преобразование.

long в long long - расширение.
long в int - стандартное преобразование.

Скорей всего повлияло, в моей модели данных long = int = 4, а long long = 8.
Какая тогда должна быть логика?
Если long = int, почему бы не выбрать функцию с int аргументом?

Если я попробую заменить long l = 2L на int l = 2, все удачно скомпилируется, из за точного соответствия.

PS: Все попытки на c++14

Comment: Очередной пример, демонстрирующий, что overloading вообще не стоит использовать. Но изучать (с целью разбираться в чужом коде) приходится.

Comment: Создал баг в [connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1445371). Очередной баг в MSVC.

Comment: Я рад что помог найти баг MSVC, хех. Чувствую себя полезным. ps: я использую g++

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Я не знаю, откуда вы взяли эту информацию о каком-то "расширении", которое якобы "имеет больше приоритет, чем стандартное преобразование".

Язык С++ признает только два типа целочисленных преобразований при выполнении ранжирования неявных преобразований в процессе overload resolution. Это *integral promotions* и *integral conversions* (см. Table 12 в 13.3.3.1.2).

Integral promotions - это преобразования, которым подвергаются "малые" целочисленные типы - `[signed/unsigned] char` и `[signed/unsigned] short`. Типы `int`, `long` и `long long` не могут подвергаться integral promotions, и к нашему случаю integral promotions никак не относятся.

Все остальные преобразования между целочисленными типами являются *integral conversions* и имеют один и тот же ранг, независимо от того, являются ли они "расширяющими", "сужающими" или еще какими. В вашем случае преобразования `long -> int` и `long -> long long` являются integral conversions.

Фактический размер типов на вашей платформе никакого значения не имеет. Ранжирование неявных преобразований полностью абстрагировано от этих размеров. Тот факт, что на вашей платформе `int` и `long` имеют одно и тоже физическое представление ничего не меняет. С точки зрения языка `int` и `long` - разные типы и между ними надо выполнять *преобразования*, пусть даже и чисто концептуальные.

(Да, в С++ есть понятие *сужающего* (narrowing) преобразования, и преобразование из `long` в `int` в общем случае является сужающим, но при выполнении ранжирования неявных целочисленных преобразований этот момент не учитывается вообще.)

В вашем случае обе функции-кандидата требуют integral conversion, т.е. преобразований одного и того же ранга. Значит вызов неоднозначен.

Comment: "long -> long long являются integral conversions." почему long -> long long является integral conversion?

Comment: Отвечу сам себе - потому что в `integral promotion` нет подходящего правила.

Comment: @ixSci: "Integral promotions" с незапамятных времен включали только очень специальный тип преобразования, существовавший еще в С. Это именно преобразования "малых" целых типов до типа `int` (или `unsigned int`), которые выполняются *безусловно*, независимо от контекста. Ни в С, ни в С++ арифметические действия [почти] никогда не выполняются в малых типах, а сначала безусловно "промотятся" до типа `int` и затем уже выполняются в типе `int`. Вот это безусловное расширение "малых" типов до типа `int` и называется Integral promotions.

Comment: почти? Разве есть исключения?

Comment: Ключевым моментом тут является именно безусловность (контекстная  независимость) преобразования. "Малый" типы промотятся до `int` *всегда*, независимо от того пристствуют ли вокруг более крупные типы. Так, например, выражение `(char) 1 + (short) 2` будет выяисляться в рамках типа `int`, как `(int) 1 + (int) 2`, несмотря на то, что в исходном выраждении никаких намеков на тип `int` нет и в помине. Вот это называется integral promotions.

Comment: Преобразования же к более крупным типам (`long`, `long long` и т.п.) никогда не делается безусловно. Преобразования к более крупным типам делаются только тогда, когда этого явно требует окружающий контекст. Именно поэтому преобразования к более крупным типам принадлежат к совсем другому классу - integral conversions.

Comment: @ixSci: Нет, на самом деле вроде исключений нет. Я когда писал "почти" думал несколько о другом - о том, что в операторах побитового сдвига `<<` и `>>` тип правого операнда не влияет на тип результата. Но это из несколько другой оперы... Также в качестве "исключения" можно рассматривать поведение левого операнда в присваивании. Но это тоже из несколько другой оперы...

Comment: @AnT , я использовал эту литературу http://valera.asf.ru/cpp/book/c09.html , а какую порекомендуете Вы, если эта плохая? (желательно на русском)

Comment: @AnT , если модель данных long > int, а long long > long, то при переводе long в int будет потеря точности, а из long в long long нет. Почему тут нет приоритетов?

Comment: "независимо от того, являются ли они "расширяющими", сужающими" или еще какими" почему так?:D

Answer (score 0):

Обе функции одинаково хороши поэтому фиксируется неоднозначность (преобразований не нужно), тогда как для int нужно преобразование.

Answer (score 0):

Дело в том, что в С++ все типы с разным названием различаются с точки зрения компилятора. И необходимы преобразования, даже несмотря на то, что их размеры совпадают. Ну, а раз необходимы преобразования, причём цепочки `long → int` и `long → long long` одинаково хороши, поэтому происходит ошибка выбора перегрузки.

Однако синомимы, объявленные с помощью typedef, не различаются.