# integral conversions/promotions и приоритеты

Tags: c++11, language-lawyer

Этот вопрос вырос из этого [вопроса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/430579/%D0%A1%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C/430609#430609).
Почему при integral conversions/promotions нет приоритетов "сужающее" или "расширяющее" в выборе перегруженного метода?

Вот примеры неоднозначностей:

```
void f(long long v) { cout << 1; }
void f(int v) { cout << 2; }
int main() {
    long l = 2L;
    f(l);
    return 0;
}


void f(char v) {cout << 1;}
void f(long v) {cout << 2;}
int main() {
    short i = 2;
    f(i);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Правила выбора конкретной функции для данного вызова в C++ самые сложные из всех языков, которые я видел.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Мне кажется, это **дефект** стандарта.

На данный момент [стандарт различает](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_cast) integral promotions и integral conversions. Integral promotion — это автоматическое преобразование типов меньше `int` в `int`, пришедшее ещё с времён C и жертвующее семантикой [ради эффективности](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24372323/276994) (всё же `int` — самый эффективный тип данных). Integral conversion — это преобразование любого целочисленного типа данных в **любой** другой (не обязательно расширяющее), которое применяется, если integral promotion оказалось недостаточно для приведения типа к нужному (оно имеет [меньший приоритет](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/overload_resolution)).

Мне кажется, когда принимались правила, считалось, что первого случая (integral promotions) будет достаточно, чтобы покрыть необходимые случаи использования, и второй случай приберегли для крайней необходимости. Теперь изменить это не так просто, потому что это может молча изменить смысл существующего кода!

Пример: вот [такой код](http://ideone.com/8HaEvl):

```
#include <iostream>

void f(long x, char y) { std::cout << "f(long, char)" << std::endl; }
void f(long long x, long long y) { std::cout << "f(long long, long long)" << std::endl; }

int main()
{
    f((long)0, (int)0);
    return 0;
}
```

в рамках текущего стандарта не приводит к двусмысленности и вызывает перегрузку `f(long, char)` (т. к. имеем одно точное совпадение и одно integral conversion). Если понизить приоритет сужающих конверсий, то теперь более подходящей перегрузкой будет `f(long long, long long)`! Таким образом, после перекомпиляции с таким стандартом поведение старых программ изменится.

Вот [предложение к изменению стандарта](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3387.html), обсуждающее ту же проблему.

---

Я намеренно несколько упрощаю ситуацию и правила для понятности.

Comment: Тоесть, если я передаю в вызов функции аргумент целочисленного типа "T", который выше int и в списке кандидатов функций с аргументом "T" функции нет, но зато есть с другими типами целочисленными, то integral conversions и неопределенность из за отсутствия приоритетов сужение или расширения?  " Integral conversion — это преобразование любого целочисленного типа данных в любой другой"

Comment: А если я передаю в вызов функции аргумент целочисленного типа "T", который меньше int и в списке функций кандидатов, функции с типом аргумента "T"  и типом int нет, но зато есть с другими типами целочисленными, то это  Integral promotion и неопределенность тк только к int?

Comment: @uskabuska: По поводу первого комментария: да. Проверка: http://ideone.com/AueqFx

Comment: @uskabuska: По поводу второго: http://ideone.com/2LkEzC (неоднозначности нет).

Comment: @uskabuska: Да, так и есть, имеем 2 шт возможных integral conversion (**не** promotion), и неоднозначность: http://ideone.com/7rOsWQ.

Comment: Спасибо Вам большое, Вы мне очень помогли.

Comment: @uskabuska: Пожалуйста!

Comment: Позвольте нам [продолжить обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25026/discussion-between-uskabuska-and-vladd).